# Viewshed Analysis for total beginner

Tags: qgis, viewshed

I am totally new to doing this using QGIS. Can anyone help me to produce the following, which I believe is commonly known as a ZTV analysis.

I am running Wein and have the Viewshed Analysis plugin loaded. I have downloaded the asc data for a single UK grid square, extracted it, converted it and then saved it as a Geotiff.

This is what I have been asked for:

We used the free 50 mm Digital Terrain Model (DTM) from the OS, gave the proposed development a height e.g. approximately 8 metres for a 2 storey house within the site boundary and viewing height of approximately 2 metres. We would sometimes ‘screen’ the ZTV by introducing shape files for areas of woodland and settlement

I really do not have a clue where to start.

Comment: This is fairly generic question, but in the context of this particular data set, OP needs to convert the DEM to 27700 (OS Open data DEMs aren't 27700, they use a different datum, which stops the plug-in from working).